# Cofinality of a $\sigma$-ideal of $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: set-theory, real-analysis, descriptive-set-theory

The *cofinality* of a partially ordered set $\left( P,\leq \right)$, written $cof(P)$, is the smallest cardinality of a subset $T$ of $P$ that is [EDIT: cofinal] in $P$, i.e. for every element $p\in P$ there is a larger element $q\in T$ such that $p\leq q$.

A *$\sigma$-ideal* $I$ of $\mathbb{R}$ is a collection of subsets of $\mathbb{R}$ that is closed under taking subsets and countable unions, i.e. $U\in I, V\subset U \Rightarrow V\in I$ and $U_{n}\in I, n<\omega \Rightarrow \cup _{n<\omega }U_{n} \in I$.

We can now define the cofinality $cof(I)$ of a $\sigma$-ideal I as the cofinality of the partial order $\left( I,\subseteq \right)$.

We can prove some neat results such that if the ideal I is nonprincipal (i.e. it is not the set of all subsets of some subset $U\subset \mathbb{R}$), then its cofinality is at least uncountable.

My question is: are there any $\sigma$-ideals of $\mathbb{R}$ whose cofinality is greater than continuum, the cardinality of $\mathbb{R}$?

EDIT: thanks for the terminology and markup tips :)

Comment: If $2^{\aleph_{0}}$ is regular, then simply take the collection of all non-stationary sets as your ideal.

Comment: Is your usage of "unbounded in $P$" standard terminology nowadays, e.g., from some textbook? If you use "unbounded in $P$" to mean "cofinal in $P$", then what do you call a subset of $P$ which merely has no upper bound in $P$?

Comment: BTW you can use [markdown](http://mathoverflow.net/help/formatting) to get bolg or italics. For example, *cofinality* and *$\sigma$-ideal* looks better than $\textit{cofinality}$ and $\sigma-ideal$. You can type this as `*cofinality*` and `*$\sigma$-ideal*`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

$\textbf{A counterexample when $2^{\aleph_{0}}$ is regular}$.

This holds if $2^{\aleph_{0}}$ is a regular cardinal. In fact, it holds for any regular cardinal. If $\kappa$ is a regular cardinal, then the ideal of non-stationary sets in $\kappa$ cannot be generated by $\kappa$ many elements. To prove this fact, suppose to the contrary that $(C_{\alpha})_{\alpha<\kappa}$ generates the filter generated by all club sets. Then let $D=\Delta_{\alpha<\kappa}C_{\alpha}$ be the diagonal intersection. Then $D$ is a club set such that for each club set $C$, we have $D\subseteq C\cup A$ for some bounded $A$. However, if $E$ is the collection of limit points of $D$, then $D\not\subseteq E\cup A$ for each bounded $A\subseteq\kappa$. This is a contradiction.

$\textbf{A counterexample that works regardless of the regularity of $2^{\aleph_{0}}$}$.

One can modify the above example to get such an ideal even when $2^{\aleph_{0}}$ is not regular. The idea is to take the filter of club sets on $P_{\kappa}(X)$ instead of $\kappa$ and generalize the above argument. Suppose that $\kappa$ is an uncountable cardinal such that $\mathfrak{c}^{<\kappa}=\mathfrak{c}$ (i.e. $\mathfrak{c}^{\lambda}=\mathfrak{c}$ for each $\lambda<\kappa$. For example, we could have $\kappa=\aleph_{1}$. Let $X$ be any set of cardinality continuum. Then define $P_{\kappa}(X)=\{R\subseteq X:|R|<\kappa\}$. Then $|P_{\kappa}(X)|=\mathfrak{c}$. A subset $\mathcal{P}\subseteq P_{\kappa}(X)$ is said to be an unbounded set if for each $P\in P_{\kappa}(X)$ there is some $Q\in X$ with $P\subseteq Q$. We say that $\mathcal{P}\subseteq P_{\kappa}(X)$ is closed if whenever $\lambda<\kappa$ and $P_{\alpha}\in\mathcal{P}$ for $\alpha<\lambda$, then $\bigcup_{\alpha<\lambda}P_{\alpha}\in\mathcal{P}$. As usual, a set is a club set if it is closed and unbounded. It is easy to show that the intersection of less than $\kappa$ club sets in $P_{\kappa}(X)$ is a club set. If $C_{x}\subseteq P_{\kappa}(X)$ for each $x\in X$, then define the diagonal intersection by letting $R\in\Delta_{x\in X}C_{x}$ iff $R\in P_{\kappa}(X)$ and $R\in C_{x}$ for each $x\in R$. It is easy to show that the diagonal intersection of club sets in $P_{\kappa}(X)$ is a club set in $P_{\kappa}(X)$. The filter generated by the club sets in $P_{\kappa}(X)$ is $\sigma$-complete and even $\kappa$-complete, but I claim that this filter is not generated by continuumly many elements.

Suppose for the sake of contradiction, that the filter generated by the club sets in $P_{\kappa}(X)$ is generated by continuumly many elements. Then let $(C_{x})_{x\in X}$ be a system of club sets that generates the filter of club sets. Then let $D=\Delta_{x\in X}C_{x}$. Then $D$ is a club set in $P_{\kappa}(X)$. Define $\uparrow x=\{R\in P_{\kappa}(X)|x\in R\}$. If $C$ is a club set, then $C_{x}\subseteq C$ for some $x\in X$. Therefore if $R\in D,x\in R$, then $R\in C_{x}\subseteq C$. In other words, for each club set $C$ there is an $x\in X$ where $D\cap\uparrow x\subseteq C$. Therefore $\{D\cap\uparrow x|x\in X\}$ generates the club filter.

Now assume that $A_{x}\in D\cap\uparrow x$ for each $x\in X$. Let $B_{x}\in P_{\kappa}(X)$ be a set such that $A_{x}\subseteq B_{x}$ but $A_{x}\neq B_{x}$. Let $E\subseteq P_{\kappa}(X)$ be the collection of all subsets $L\in P_{\kappa}(X)$ such that if $x\in L$, then $B_{x}\subseteq L$. Then $E$ is a club set. However, $A_{x}\in D\cap\uparrow x$, but $A_{x}\not\in E$. Therefore $D\cap\uparrow x\not\subseteq E$ for each $x\in X$. This is a contradiction. We conclude that the filter generated by the club sets in $P_{\kappa}(X)$ cannot be generated with continuumly many elements.

Answer (score 5):

If the continuum hypothesis holds, then there is such an ideal. Indeed, we need only to assume that $2^\omega\lt
2^{\omega_1}$, a weakening of CH.

Consider the tree $T=2^{\lt\omega_1}$ of all binary sequences of
some countable ordinal length. This tree has continuum many nodes,
and so let us associate with every node of $T$ a distinct real
number. If $s\in 2^{\omega_1}$ is an $\omega_1$-branch through
$T$, let $A_s$ be the set of reals appearing on the branch $s$.
Let $I$ be the $\sigma$-ideal on $\mathbb{R}$ generated by these sets $\{A_s\mid s\in
2^{\omega_1}\}$. Thus, a set is in $I$ if and only if it is
contained in $\bigcup_n A_{s_n}$, for some countable collection of
$\omega_1$-branches $s_n\in 2^{\omega_1}$ through $T$.

I claim that no continuum many sets can be cofinal in $I$. To see
this, suppose toward contradiction that $J\subset I$ and $J$ has
size continuum. Each $B\in J$ is contained in some countable union
$\bigcup_n A_{s_n^B}$. In particular, there are only $2^\omega$
many branches $s_n^B$ mentioned for $B\in J$. But since there are
$2^{\omega_1}$ many branches through $T$, which is strictly larger
than the continuum by our assumption, there is some
$\omega_1$-branch $s$ through $T$ that is not $s_n^B$ for any
$B\in J$. But it now follows that $A_s$ is not contained in any
element of $J$, and so $J$ is not cofinal.

Comment: The cofinality of $I$ is precisely $2^{\omega_1}$, by the same argument.

Answer (score 3):

A set $X \subseteq \mathbb R$ is of ``strong measure zero'' if the following holds:

- For every sequence $(\varepsilon_n:n\in \mathbb N)$ of positive numbers there is a sequence $(I_n:n\in \mathbb N)$ of intervals such that $I_n$ has length $\varepsilon_n$, and $X$ is covered by the union of these intervals.

The smz (strong measure zero) sets are a proper subideal of the ideal of Lebesgue null sets, as the classical Cantor set (and indeed any perfect set) is not smz.

It is consistent that the cofinality of the $\sigma$-ideal smz is greater than continuum (e.g. under CH).  It is also consistent that this cofinality is equal to the continuum, or less than the continuum.

(Teruyuki Yorioka, *The cofinality of the strong measure zero ideal*.
J. Symbolic Logic 67 (2002), no. 4, 1373–1384. MR1955243)